# Why is my scrollbar not working in my CTKinter Frame?

Tags: python, tkinter, customtkinter

I am using customtkinter for building a GUI. In my Window i have a Frame with different widgets in it.
some of the widgets are out of the frames boundaries. I want the user to be able to scroll down within the frame the be able to acces all the other widgets like different labels, images or buttons. I tried using a Scrollbar for that. The scroll bar actually gets displayed in the frame but you cant move it.
I am sorry if this is a dumb question but i could not find any solutions. I am still new to Tkinter and customtkinter.

I searched online for a solution and found out that you need to set a command for the scrollbar. I tried doing that but it wasnt working:

```
file_manager_frame = ctk.CTkFrame(app,750,230,border_width=0,fg_color="#172a38",border_color="#000000")
file_manager_frame.pack()
file_manager_frame.place(x=270,y=430)

scrollbar = ctk.CTkScrollbar(file_manager_frame)
scrollbar.pack(side="right")
scrollbar.place(x=725,y=40,relwidth=0.0275,relheight=0.8)
scrollbar.configure(command=file_manager_frame.yview)
```

I am getting the following error:

```
    scrollbar.configure(command=file_manager_frame.yview)
                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'CTkFrame' object has no attribute 'yview'
```

I found a ton of solutions but all those people where using a Canvas with the frame but i am only using the frame.

Comment: `CTkFrame` widgets aren't scrollable - you'll have to use a [CTkScrollableFrame](https://github.com/TomSchimansky/CustomTkinter/wiki/CTkScrollableFrame) instead

Comment: file_manager_frame is a frame widget.

Comment: The *reason* why people are using a Canvas in conjunction with scrollbars is that a Canvas is one of the few widget types that support scrollbars.